# Is it possible to use Flowbite with Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use flowbite in next13.
I'm trying to create a Apple Login button in the component directory. However, an error occurred whether the button of the flowbite was a client side component, so I tried to make it a client side component through 'use client'. However, the following error still occurs. What should I do?

> You're importing a component that needs flushSync. It only works in a Client Component but
> none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

/src/app/login/page.tsx

```js
import AppleLogin from "@/components/main/atom/AppleLogin";
import Card from "@/components/wrapper/Card";
import Grid from "@/components/wrapper/Grid";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid grid="col-span-3"></Grid>
      <Grid grid="col-span-6" className="h-[500px]">
        <Card className="flex flex-col items-center px-[100px] py-[50px] justify-between">
          <div className="w-full text-heading2 font-bold">Login</div>
          <div className=" flex flex-col w-full h-[246px] justify-between">
            <AppleLogin />
          </div>
          <Link
            href="/test"
            className="underline underline-offset-4 text-[#FF5F05] font-bold"
          >
            test
          </Link>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid grid="col-span-3"></Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

/src/components/main/atom/AppleLogin.tsx

```js
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "flowbite-react";
import Apple from "public/icons/brand/Apple.svg";
export default function AppleLogin() {
  return (
    <Button className="w-full h-[48px] bg-[#000000]">
      <Apple />
    </Button>
  );
}
```

I tried to erase 'use client'; but it didn't work out.
What should I do?

Comment: I think that error is happening because Grid and Card components are client components, meaning that they use hooks or things like that. You can make home component client component as remove error.